# Creating a tensor where each input can have multiple answers

Tags: tensorflow

I have a problem where the inputs X can have multiple correct answers

```
X1 -> Y1
X1 -> Y2
X1 -> Y3
X2 -> Y2
X2 -> Y4
X3 -> Y1
```

Here X1 has (Y1, Y2, Y3) as labels, X2 has (Y2, Y4) as labels.

If we create an MLP which predicts

```
# tf Graph input                                                                                                    
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

# Construct model                                                                                                   
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, activation_fn, weights, biases, dbg)

# Define loss and optimizer                                                                                         
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
```

Here, the cost function is comparing the model prediction of the X vector with the Y vector.

I am checking if **the model can predict any of the correct labels for any input**. Given X1, if the model predicts (Y1  or Y2 or Y3), I am fine. How can I construct the problem for this?

Comment: Calc all costs (Y vs Y1 and Y vs Y2 and so forth) and then take the minimum of those costs

Answer (score 0):

I think having multiple labels such as `X1 -> Y1, X1 -> Y2` may hurt your model. If any of the correct labels is OK, then just use one label for input features: `X1->Y1`.

If you don't have too many labels, you can think of combining them as well:

```
Z1: Y1, Y2, Y3 
Z2: Y2, Y4
```

Then, you can have input features only one label:

```
X1-> Z1
X2-> Z2
```

Comment: I understand that multiple labels may hurt the model. I want to try it. I can do it in liblinear. While the combination is possible, there are too many combinations in my data. Do note that combination is stricter than any of them. I want the label of X1 to be Y1 OR Y2 OR Y3. Z1 is stricter

Comment: @trialcritic sounds good. You may also try all ideas and see which one is the best. Please let me know the results.

Comment: @Sung_Kim I tried my best to do this and could not. Any suggestions? If I have a feed dict tensor, I cannot update every row of the tensor.